# Should I create a new question?

Tags: support, asking-questions, etiquette

I forgot a minus sign everywhere and I made a question wrong.

I asked
[The differential entropy cannot be negative for pdf in (0,1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445137/the-differential-entropy-cannot-be-negative-for-pdf-in-0-1) but the question should have been *positive* instead of *negative*.

The accepted answer gives an answer to the *negative* question and an answer for the *positive* question in the comments.

I want to edit the question, but if I edit it, the accepted answer will not correspond at all and will be very misleading.

- Is it ok if I create a second question using *positive* and answer it based on the comments of the *negative* answer? (adding a reference)
- Or should I edit it?

Comment: See also: [Question edited to change meaning](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2304) (and other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2304)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One should *not* edit a question in such a way that it renders existing good answers invalid. If you do not note the error in time, just leave the post around if it makes sense.

Yes, it is alright to ask the originally intended question in a new post, and it is also fine to self-answer it if you want to do this.

To avoid confusion, I recommend to write a comment on the new post, or even in the new post, that explains the situation.

Comment: You got a typo 'on the new post, or even in the new post'

Comment: Done: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517995/differential-entropy-cannot-be-positive-for-pdf-in-0-1/3517996#3517996

Comment: Sorry, I do not see the typo. Maybe what I meant to say is confusingly expressed though,